# Is there an easier way to compile this project

Tags: c, cmake, sdl, clion

Under Linux(Ubuntu) I'm writing a CMakeLists.txt with CLion to compile my project which is a little game written in C. How do I fix these errors?

Here's a [link](https://easyupload.io/ybuhcv) to the entire source code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

I have tried to rewrite my .h files. It was primarily an issue about linking SDL and  SDL_images.

I have tried to compile the main with `gcc main.c -o main -lSDL -lSDL_image`.

Here's the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(SOKOBAN)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lmingw32")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL)
find_package(SDL_image)



set(SOURCE_FILES main.c jeu.c jeu.h editeur.c editeur.h
        fichiers.c fichiers.h Constantes.h  hsokoban.h)

add_executable(SOKOBANR ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(SOKOBANR SDL_image SDL)
```

The error is:

````
[ 20%] Linking C executable SOKOBANR
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:12: multiple definition of `jouer'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/main.c.o:/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:12: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/lib/libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/main.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:72: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:76: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:80: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:84: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:72: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o:/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:76: more undefined references to `deplacerJoueur' follow
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/fichiers.c.o: In function `sauvegarderNiveau':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/fichiers.c:67: undefined reference to `fprint'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/build.make:128: recipe for target 'SOKOBANR' failed
make[3]: *** [SOKOBANR] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'SOKOBANR' failed
make: *** [SOKOBANR] Error 2```
````

Comment: I'm assuming `deplacerJoueur` is a function you wrote?  If so, make sure you're compiling the source file where the function is implemented.

Comment: It's in jeu.h defined as a prototype. Also, since you mentioned that, when I hover my mouse pointer over the function jouer in jeu.h I see SDL_Surface as an unknown type name .

Comment: Where is it implemented?  You need to make sure you're building that source file.  Your build errors are because the linker can't find that function's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get such errors you need to look into each of them:

---

```
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:12: multiple definition of `jouer'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/main.c.o:/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:12: first defined here
```

The linker thinks that you have (at least) two definitions of `jouer`. Since both referenced locations are the same I assume that you 1. include "jeu.c" instead of "jeu.h" in your "main.c", and 2. link both "main.o" and "jeu.o".

---

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/lib/libSDL.a when searching for -lSDL
```

The library "libSDL.a" you provide is not compatible to the target system. Your target system seems to be Linux.

For which system is the library?

Did you compile it yourself or did you download it?

---

```
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/main.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:72: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:76: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:80: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:84: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o: In function `jouer':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:72: undefined reference to `deplacerJoueur'
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/jeu.c.o:/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/jeu.c:76: more undefined references to `deplacerJoueur' follow
```

There are references (calls) of `deplacerJoueur` but you don't define it. Or the source file with the definition (implementation) is not added to the list of modules.

---

```
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/fichiers.c.o: In function `sauvegarderNiveau':
/home/mahamad/github/SOKOBAN/SOKOBAN/fichiers.c:67: undefined reference to `fprint'
```

This is clearly a typo. You mean `fprintf()` with a trailing 'f' for sure.

---

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Because of all the errors the linker is not successful, and it tells you.

---

```
CMakeFiles/SOKOBANR.dir/build.make:128: recipe for target 'SOKOBANR' failed
```

Because of all the errors the build is not successful, and it tells you.

Comment: By following a course on C and been stuck on this part for a months. Anyways everything you said helped as I had the functions used in another function and the order of included in the main.c wasn't the best also. Merci !

Comment: Fixed the target library issue by downloading the right one and replaced it in use/include on my system